# use laravel veriable in Jquery Image Slug

Tags: jquery, laravel

I HAVE Image Slug Like:

```
url({{asset('landingpage/slider_images')}}/{{$img->slider_img}})
```

And I want to to use in this in following Jquery

```
$(function(){

    var fadeShow = $(".background").fadeShow({

        shuffle: true,

        speed: 5000,

        images: ['{{asset('landingpage/slider_images')}}/{{$img->slider_img}}']

    });

});
```

But its Not working for Me it returns the following error

[image]

Comment: is this all in the same blade view file? based on the error we wouldn't know if it is that first code block or the second one causing the error ... also you can simplify your URL generation by using string concatenation `asset('landingpage/slider_images/'. $img->slider_img)`

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all. The thing you're trying to use ($img) is undefined. If you are not retrieving it in your blade view, in some way, then ensuring that it is being passed to the blade view (as $img) in your controller.

Comment: But Its working here 
"style="background: url({{asset('landingpage/slider_images')}}/{{$img->slider_img}});"

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommended to do it like that

balde :

```
<span id="slider_img" style='display:none;'> {{ $img->slider_img ?? "" }} </>
```

js :

```
$(function(){

    var fadeShow = $(".background").fadeShow({

        shuffle: true,

        speed: 5000,

        images: ['{{asset('landingpage/slider_images')}}/'+$('#slider_img').text()]

    });

});
```